# Construction of “females representatives”

Tags: adjectives, plural-forms

In [a Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/jul/20/republican-attacks-hillary-clinton-witch-trial-politics), I stumbled over this sentence:

> These kind of men deter women from entering politics, when more females representatives is exactly what America needs.

I would have expected to read *female representatives* here (like *green leaves*, not *greens leaves*). Why is it *females*? Isn’t it used as an adjective here?

It doesn’t seem to be a typo, since I found a few similar cases in a Google search, such as this one in a 2005 book:

> As a result of (…), Wales has one of the highest proportions of females representatives in the world, (…)

Comment: Maybe author speaks French and just slipped up matching adjective and noun plurality.

Comment: Just cause you found something twice doesn't mean it can't be a mistake both times :)

Comment: @curiousdannii: Obviously; but it’s hard to tell. It _could_ be a (correct) language peculiarity after all. I also found a few more occurrences, I just didn’t cite every single one.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have certainly found a typographical error. That you found multiple examples
is testament not to its correctness, but only to the frequency of the phrase "female representatives" and to the declining standards of proofreading in the Age of the 24-hour News Cycle.

(p.s.: I just noticed that *The Grauniad* threw in a "these kind" for good measure!)

Comment: It might have been an attempt to disambiguate between "a representative who is female" and "a representative who is representing females"?

Comment: @Cronax - I doubt that, if only because I'm not aware of any government in the world that has representatives specifically for women.

Comment: @Cronax The latter would have to be *females' representatives* anyway, making the example in the question still incorrect.

Comment: "You have certainly found a typographical error." - and that's why the satirical magazine "Private Eye" usually called it the Grauniad. Actually, it's got better at proofreading in recent years, not worse. Back in 2011 it told the world that "Spanish voters are have thrown out it's current government and brung in a new conservative government" - followed by the assertion that "Belgium currently has government." http://politicalscrapbook.net/2011/11/grauniad-grammatical-errors/

Comment: @alephzero but ... surely by now everyone understands that "belgium" does not exist?

Comment: @Adam You spoilt my wee bit o fun.

Comment: Why are you repeatedly editing minor typos and errors into your post?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I was having what seemed to me harmless fun, with an interesting self-referential aspect. In future I <s>will</s> shall be more circumspect.

Comment: @stangdon FWIW https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_for_Women_(Australia)

Answer (score 6):

I can't but absolutely agree with P.E.Dant: It's an error no matter how you look at "female" -- as a part of a compound noun or a determiner.

It also might be that "women representatives", which appears to be [more frequent than "female representatives"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=female+representatives%2Cfemales+representatives%2Cwomen+representatives&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfemale%20representatives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomen%20representatives%3B%2Cc0), made someone decide that "females" wouldn't be incorrect, which actually is.

Anyways, Google Ngram Viewer doesn't find the "females representatives" collocation.

Answer (score 0):

### Females'

They forgot to add the possessive apostrophe.  Add an `s'` to `female` when you want to add possessiveness to it.  Add just add`s` when you want to pluralize it.

`Female representatives` is using the word `female` as an adjective.  They are describing the representatives.

`Females' representatives` does not describe the representative but rather, it demonstrates who the representatives are representing, who they are sponsoring, who they work for.

Compare it with these other examples:

> Lawyers' clients
>
> Lucas' toys

If a noun ends in `-s` then to make it possessive, you can't just do `Jones's`, because then it will sound like

### Joneseses

Comment: It would sound *Joneses* one "es", not two. That is precisely how it should be pronounced.

Comment: A little hyperbole never hurt anyone :P

Answer (score -1):

It would appear that the phrase *females representatives* treats **females** as a collective whole, meaning that the females themselves are the ones being represented.

Comment: I think not: the sentence is concerned with the gender of the representatives, not their constituents.